# Why doesn't selectRow(x) work?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QTableView and have used QStandardItemModel* to set it up with the format (not a complete, working, code sample - it is merely for illustration):

```
    memoryModel_ = new QStandardItemModel(100, 2, this);
    memoryModel_->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, new QStandardItem(QString("Index")));
    memoryModel_->setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, new QStandardItem(QString("Instruction")));
    memoryModel_->setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, new QStandardItem(QString("Parameter")));

    ui->theMemory->setModel(memoryModel_);


 for (int row=0; row<=50; ++row){
        QStandardItem *firstCol = new QStandardItem(QString::number(row));
        QStandardItem *secondCol = new QStandardItem(QString::number(getValue(), 16));
        QStandardItem *thirdCol = new QStandardItem(QString::number(getParameter(), 16));
        memoryModel_->setItem(row,0,firstCol);
        memoryModel_->setItem(row,1,secondCol);
        memoryModel_->setItem(row,2,thirdCol);
   }
```

When the current value is incremented I call

```
ui->theMemory->selectRow(getCurrent());  // get current returns an int between 1 and 50
```

But no selection is shown.  The selectionMode is SingleSelection.

Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: What does `getCurrent` return?

Comment: …and what’s the value of Limit and memoryMax?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld, I have edited the code to fill them in and reduce potential red herrings

Comment: @Amartel, getCurrent returns an in between 0 and the number of lines added to the control (in this case they represent machine code instructions read in from a file)

Comment: Simple test project, based on the above code, works as expected. Which means the problem is somewhere else. May be you do something after selecting row?

Comment: @Amartel, thanks!  When you said that I knew it must be something else other than what I was looking at and spotted the issue!!